# python subprocess is working in interactive mode but in not script

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

In windows I have to execute a command like below:

```
process = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\xxx.exe', '-n', '@iseasn2a7.sd.xxxx.com:3944#dc', '-d', r'D:\test\file.txt'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
process.communicate()
```

This works fine in python interactive mode, but not at all executing from the python script.

What may be the issue ?

Comment: @Ram,  There is no error output.

Comment: If you print the return value, what is printed? `print process.communicate()`

Comment: It prints what is printed from process.communicate() from interactive mode, but execution is not happened.

Comment: Do you mean the script **with** `print` statement does not print anything?

Comment: No, with `print process.communicate()` statement only its printing. but not with only  `process.communicate()`

Answer (score 1):

[`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) itself does not print anything, but it returns the stdout, stderr output. Beside that because the code specified `stdout=PIPE, stderr=...` when it create `Popen`, it catch the outputs (does not let the sub-process print output directly to the stdout of the parent process)

You need to print the return value manually:

```
process = ....
output, error = process.communicate()
print output
```

If you don't want that, don't catch stdout output by omit `stdout=PIPE, stderr=...`.

Then, you don't need to use `communicate`, but just `wait`:

```
process = subprocess.Popen([...], shell=True)
process.wait()
```

Or, you can use `subprocess.call` which both execute sub-process and wait its termination:

```
subprocess.call([...], shell=True)
```

Comment: but in interactive mode, it prints without print statement.

Comment: @PDK, Because the interactive mode prints the value of the expression (return value for function call). Try `1 + 2` in interactive mode and in script.

Comment: @PDK, It is not. It is a screencast I just recorded.

Comment: The system command is not executing at all from the script. Is there anyway I can verify the exit status of the command executed in python ?

Comment: @kumarprd wait, call both return exit status.

Comment: found the f**g culprit. I was using a `shell=True` in another `subprocess.call` command before this subprocess . After removing that the command executed. But why this `shell=True` was causing issues ?

Comment: @kumarprd, I cannot answer that without more information. Could you provide the minimal code that demonstrate your problem?